# Reload FooTable for each angular api response

Tags: angularjs, pagination, footable

I'm using AngularJS with FooTable to show data in a table.

I have an issue when updating FooTable content.

This is when more than 10 Records
[image: For more than 10 records]

This is when updating with no records. FooTable shows pagination
[image]

When I click pagination (2), old records are showing
[image]

This is when updating with less than 10 records. The pagination is gone now.
[image]

My FooTable is,

```
<table class="table" data-paging="true" data-filtering="true" data-sorting="true"  data-state="true">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-breakpoints="xs">Session ID</th>
            <th data-breakpoints="xs">Date</th>
            <th data-breakpoints="xs">Cost</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="(index,session) in sessions" class="panel" repeat-end="onEnd()" data-expanded="true">
            <td>
                <span ng-if="session.sid">{{session.sid}}</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span  ng-if="session.sid">{{session.date}}</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span  ng-if="session.cost_to_interviewer">{{session.cost_to_interviewer}}</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

First time I initialized FooTable as

> FooTable.init('.table', {});

The response(in object form) stores `$scope.sessions`. Then AngularJS will display this content.

I tried to debug but failed. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Hi, where you add the tag for the pager or Is it an inbuilt pager come along with code for the table. Can you please share that also?

Comment: Hi @AlexisToby, thank you quick response. I'm sorry if I'm wrong, You mean 'data-paging="true" ' ?? I mentioned in the table only. And No code added except mentioned above.

Comment: Hi, No problems, can you please share the function code where you assign values to the **$scope.sessions**. We can add a validation there.

Comment: This is code snippet:

$http.get(baseAuth.getUrl(<url>), {headers: headers})
        .then(function(response){
         $scope.sessions = response.data.sessions;
            $scope.totalScheduled = response.data.total_scheduled_count;
            $scope.totalSuccess = response.data.success_count;
            
            
        },function(response){
         console.log("error while getting sessions details");
         console.log(response);
        });

Comment: Please find code here http://www.chopapp.com/#rglyjvan

Comment: Thank you for the code, in between I added an answer below, I hope it will help.

Comment: @satish_srg if possible please share your full code.

Answer (score 0):

please assign a dynamic value to the data-paging attribute.

In controller, after assigning the value to $scope.sessions, please add the following code.

```
 if($scope.sessions.length>0){
  $scope.dataPager = true;
 }else{
  $scope.dataPager = false
 };
```

And assign this $scope.dataPager to data-paging attribute.

`<table class="table" data-paging="dataPager" data-filtering="true" data-sorting="true"  data-state="true">`

Comment: I understand this logic and tried. But it's not working and showing all results with no pagination. So more than 10 results also displayed in one shot.

Comment: Have you checked the value of $scope.dataPager is as expected as per the situation?